# Why are there Stormtroopers in Solo?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, solo-a-star-wars-story

I just watched *Solo* the movie. And in the initial scenes there are Stormtroopers all over Corellia.

I can’t make sense of it: Stormtroopers were not created until Episode 1 after Obi-Wan brought them back with him and starting the Clone Wars under the republic.

Even the Empire they served under Palpatine wasn’t brought to existence until he made his coup. What’s more Darth Maul seems to be in the picture as a top member of the Empire while he was the apprentice of Palpatine aka Darth Sidious?

What’s going on with the timeline here?

Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Having not seen "Solo" - I do not know what the opening scene that you are referring to.  Perhaps you can provide additional details (is it a flashback or something?).  However, I believe that based on Han Solo being Younger than Obi-Wan, and a little older than Luke, the events in Solo would take place after Episode 3 and before Episode 4.

Comment: Because I realized I was confused and the question didn’t make sense anymore. I somehow imagined Solo was already in Episode I but actually he appeared in episode IV.  Chewie appeared in episode III before he got kicked out of his planet. So the timeline makes sense, except for the appearance of Darth Maul at the end, but it was probably not Maul but a guy of the same species.

Comment: @Benjamin It's Darth Maul; he doesn't actually die in Episode I (despite being cut in half). See his [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darth_Maul#Appearances) for details; it's even the same actor from Episode I.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The movie takes place between episodes three and four.  This is evidenced in a number of ways:

They constantly talk about the empire.  This didn't exist until Palpatine took over.  Before that it was a relatively peaceful republic.

Stormtroopers everywhere.

Before the execution of Order 66, Chewbacca lived on his home planet with his family-tribe. Yoda specifically addresses one of the wookies as Chewbacca before he escapes into hiding. He would not have been imprisoned, or his people enslaved, if the battle on his planet from Episode 3 had not already occurred.  Chewbacca makes the choice to stay and help Han rather than stay with the wookies he rescues in the Solo movie.  He also lacks his trademark sash-belt-thing during Episode 3.

There's talk of starting up a rebellion.  What would they have been rebelling against if this was before the Sith took over? The rebellion we do know of was against the Empire.

Darth Maul's got robo-legs now.  You can hear the servos or whatever activating when he stands up.  There were no such noises in Episode 1, so the legs were acquired later, after losing his biological ones in that horrible light saber accident.

Comment: "horrible light saber accident." - Solo in episode 9 confirmed.

Comment: There is another clear piece of evidence... Han’s age. Although we don’t know his exact age; he’s clearly not old enough for Solo to have taken place near episode one.

Answer (score 5):

Prequel trilogy (episode 1 to 3) has Clone Troopers. They are all flash clones of Jango Fett (Boba Fett's "father", although technically Boba is also a Jango clone), and they all look alike without the masks.

From episode 4 to 8, there are StormTroopers, which are not clones. They are individuals, which would account for different body shapes. Finn was a stormtrooper (under the first order regime).

Rogue One, and Solo, both take place after episode 3, and before episode 4.

Darth Maul, didn't die in episode 1 after being cut in half. He appears in both animated series, Star Wars Clone Wars (which takes place between ep 2 and 3), and SW Rebels (which takes place between ep 3 and 4). In Solo he is revealed as the leader of Crimson Dawn, and Dryden Vos and Qi'ra work for him. He is no longer a Sith, and the only sith left by then are Emperor Palpatine (Darth Sidious) and Darth Vader.